# Facebook app submission keeps getting rejected

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, submission

I have made website where people can logon to with Facebook.
Ik keep getting this message every time I submit my request.

> Your app's Facebook Login button does not work. Please make sure the
>   provided test user can successfully and consistently log in with the
>   Facebook Login button. See more about authentication.

Even though my created test user can login with IE, FF and Chrome.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same thing. I think you need to put the facebook javascript code in your website for them to see. I think that it is a bot reviewing your app, not a person, and it does not see it.

Comment: Nope, apps are reviewed by real people. But there can be misunderstandings when your usage instructions are not clear enough. Submitting additional screenshots/screencasts can help too.